# jQuery getJSON syntax error on a valid JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, firefox, mime-types

I have the following json document

```
// json.json
[  
   {  
      "title":"title1",
      "value":12234
   },
   {  
      "title":"title2",
      "value":"some text"
   },
   {  
      "title":"title3",
      "value":"12qwerty234"
   },
   {  
      "title":"title4",
      "value":123.5
   }
]
```

I am using jQuery to load it. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("json.json", {},function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
            $("form").append($('<label for="'+i+'">'+obj.title+'</label>'));
            $("form").append($('<input id="'+i+'" value="'+obj.value+'" type="text"/><br>'));
        });
    });
});
```

My problem is, that I am getting a syntax error in Firefox. I load `json.json` as a local file.
Here is a screenshot (***the error says "syntax error at line 1"***)

[image]

Note, that form has been generated successfully.

**Edit :**
Here is another screenshot from Chrome when running python `SimpleHTTPServer`:

[image]

Comment: And what does the error say ?

Comment: Nothing, it just points to the first line of the json file.

Comment: I just tested on Firefox (23.0.1) and it works fine for me. Could your JSON file contain an invisible character? Try recreating the JSON file by copying and pasting the JSON from your post.

Comment: You did save that JSON file as UTF8 ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you're using a local file, so a mime type of "text/xml" is implied and hence Firefox will try to parse it as XML into `.responseXML` of the underlying XHR object. This of course fails.

You may just ignore this, or specify the `mimeType` yourself:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "json.json",
    mimeType: "application/json",
    success: function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
            $("form").append($('<label for="'+i+'">'+obj.title+'</label>'));
            $("form").append($('<input id="'+i+'" value="'+obj.value+'" type="text"/><br>'));
        });
    }
});
```

PS: Using plain XHR you would use [`overrideMimeType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType%28%29)

Comment: also fails for me on localhost / local xml with overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=UTF16") on characters like ü,ä,ö

Answer (score 4):

I ran the same code on a webserver and no syntax error is generated. While it generates a syntax error when loaded from file:///. SO, it's basically the "scheme".

Comment: Well, I tried to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` from my directory, but that didn't work. Was it supposed to?

Comment: Yes, it was supposed to work fine. Tested it at my end with Python version 2.7.3 and it worked with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think, error produced because of json file is a local file. Try to load with your webserver, like nginx or apache.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue of syntax error 4 in json, while i was having correct json set.

I was unable to find the solution, then i used a trick of making json to php array.
You can use the same, if you find it useful though.

Sample Code:

```
$json = '
   {  

      "title":"title4",
      "value":123.5
   }';

   $json = str_replace("{", "", $json);
   $json = str_replace("}", "", $json);

   $jsonArr = explode(",", $json);
   $jsonArray = array();

   foreach($jsonArr as $json){

        $jsonTmpArr = explode(":", $json);
        $jsonArray[trim($jsonTmpArr[0])] = trim($jsonTmpArr[1]);
   }
   
print_r($jsonArray);
```