# Getting "not well-formed" error when loading file with JSON object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm loading a local file that contains a JSON object which has been validated by both [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)  and [freeformater](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html) and I'm getting a `not well-formed` error in Firefox's console.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677902/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox-when-loading-json-file-with-xmlhttprequest) and tried to use that but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the text in the file:

```
    {
    "CallsStats": [
        {
            "name": "Sales",
            "CallsWaiting": "1",
            "OnInboundACDCalls": "0",
            "LongestWaitTime": "00:01:14",
            "LongestOnHoldTime": "N/A",
            "Queue_Interval": {
                "name": "CurrentShift",
                "CallsAbandoned": "1",
                "CallsEntered": "18",
                "CallsAnswered": "16",
                "AverageWaitTime": "00:01:09",
                "AverageHoldTime": "00:00:29",
                "AverageTalkTime": "00:03:42"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Marketing",
            "CallsWaiting": "0",
            "OnInboundACDCalls": "0",
            "LongestWaitTime": "N/A",
            "LongestOnHoldTime": "N/A",
            "Queue_Interval": {
                "name": "CurrentShift",
                "CallsAbandoned": "0",
                "CallsEntered": "0",
                "CallsAnswered": "0",
                "AverageWaitTime": "N/A",
                "AverageHoldTime": "N/A",
                "AverageTalkTime": "N/A"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Support",
            "CallsWaiting": "14",
            "OnInboundACDCalls": "14",
            "LongestWaitTime": "00:04:42",
            "LongestOnHoldTime": "00:02:48",
            "Queue_Interval": {
                "name": "CurrentShift",
                "CallsAbandoned": "816",
                "CallsEntered": "2696",
                "CallsAnswered": "1349",
                "AverageWaitTime": "00:03:36",
                "AverageHoldTime": "00:00:13",
                "AverageTalkTime": "00:03:27"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my code:

```
function loadJson() {
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'sampledata.json', 
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    success:function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
}
```

I don't know if it helps, but this is what the console shows:
[image]

I tried before with `$.getJSON` and was getting the same result.

***EDITS TO THE QUESTION***

I tried what James Montagne suggested in the comments (I thought that was the what `$.getJSON` would do automatically... And this is what I got:
[image]

So I realized that some invisible characters were a problem and I got rid of them.

Now I'm able to load the file as text and convert it to a JSON object using `JSON.parse(data)` but still, it shows an error:
[image]

What could it be, and should I be concerned?

Comment: Try changing the dataType to "text" and see what you are actually getting back as a response.  Perhaps it's not what you think it is (server side error message, etc.)

Comment: @JamesMontagne Great, that helped!!! See my edits, though.

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

Comment: @HastaPasta - still getting the same syntax error. But it got solved after specifying the mime type as per [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291390/jquery-getjson-syntax-error-on-a-valid-json)

Comment: @JamesMontagne - do you want to a submit an answer?